# Bootstrap change image according to device

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to show different images in different devices (not background image). Is it possible to do using bootstrap 3.x like the following?

For large screen

```
<img src="large-image.jpg" />
```

for medium device

```
<img src="medium-image.jpg" />
```

for small device

```
<img src="small-image.jpg" />
```

and so on.

Thanks in advance.

**N.B. Finally I have found a good solution by myself. See the accepted answer below.**

Comment: Good thinking Siddiqui ! Really i appreciate it

Comment: http://adaptive-images.com/ -- server side code that you put your one largest image in your html and then it creates images for each break point for the actual device. This is used a lot. Here's the proposal for something client side: http://html5doctor.com/html5-adaptive-images-end-of-round-one/

Comment: Sounds good both for server side and client side (need to wait for all browser support).

Comment: good question but can't upvote as you found your answer without putting it here

Comment: @ElChapo See my answer after your comment, Thanks for remind me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After @EIChapo's comment on this 2 years back question, I have search and read a lot of articles for this solution. As all modern browser except IE [supports `<picture>` tag](http://caniuse.com/#feat=picture) when I'm posting this answer. There is a bulletproof solution based on Dave Newton's [article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/05/how-to-avoid-duplicate-downloads-in-responsive-images/).

What we need to do is as following:

```html
<picture alt="fancy pants">
    <!-- loaded by browsers that support picture and that support one of the sources -->
    <source srcset="big.jpg 1x, big-2x.jpg 2x, big-3x.jpg" type="image/jpeg" media="(min-width: 40em)" />
    <source srcset="med.jpg 1x, med-2x.jpg 2x, big-3x.jpg" type="image/jpeg" />

    <!-- loaded by IE 8+, non-IE browsers that don’t support picture, and browsers that support picture but cannot find an appropriate source -->
    <![if gte IE 8]>
    <object data="fallback.jpg" type="image/jpeg"></object>
    <span class="fake-alt">fancy pants</span>
    <![endif]>

    <!-- loaded by IE 6 and 7 -->
    <!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <img src="fallback.jpg" alt="fancy pants" />
    <![endif]-->
</picture>
```

```css
.fake-alt {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">  
        <img class="img-responsive" src="layouts/layouts.PNG" /> <!--Mobile-->
    </div>
    <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-12 hidden-md hidden-lg">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="layouts/05.png" /> <!--Tab-->
    </div>
    <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-12 hidden-lg">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="layouts/06.png" /> <!--Desktop-->
    </div>
    <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md col-lg-12">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="layouts/Layout_100.png" /> <!--Large-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't get into bootply right now to confirm this, but doesn't this load all the files, but only displays the relevant one? I would guess (yes guess) that OP wants to avoid loading unviewed files...

Comment: Yes this loads all the files ! to avoid postback when resizing the window! we have only four types of screen sizes (xs, sm, md, lg) so we load only 4 images. No performance issue will be there

Comment: I think there will be performance issue if you're loading a large image, medium image, small image and xs image, as oppsed to just a single small image.

Comment: If you loading while resizing means rendering will be slow na ?

Comment: not resizing while loading at all, but selecting the right image to load based on screensize. just once

Comment: Finally @Jake745 post helps me for my little web application. But yes, it is a performance issue and no problem for me, I am finding a better way to do that though.

Comment: Thank you Siddiqui Noor, if my answer helps means pls tick it

Comment: Wha'ts the point to load all four images when you only need one??

Comment: All the four images are needed, it will be displayed based on the resolutions

Comment: No, this isn't a good solution because it'll load all the images. See my answer after 2 years I found a solution.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `<img>` tag and provide other images in the `srcset` attribute

```html
<img src="small.jpg" srcset="medium.jpg 1000w, large.jpg 2000w" alt="yah">
```

It is described in detail here:

https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-youre-just-changing-resolutions-use-srcset/

Answer (score 4):

If you want to load only the image relevant to the screen-size, I think the best way is with javascript. Create versions of your photos, and in this case the script looks for an `img` with `"600x400"` in the filename, and replaces it with `"1200x800"` when the screensize is bigger than 767px.

DEMO: http://www.bootply.com/Y8XECJpGjS#

#### Javascript

```js
if ($(window).width() > 767) {
    $("img[src$='600x400']").each(function() {
        var new_src = $(this).attr("src").replace('600x400', '1200x800'); 
        $(this).attr("src", new_src); 
    });
}
```

#### HTML

```html
<div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="//placehold.it/600x400">
</div>
```

NOTE: this example uses placehold.it images, but obviously you will create your own image versions, include something to identify them in the filename (i.e. 600px, small, v1, etc), and then use that unique string as the find/replace strings in the script. i.e. If your filenames are `photo-small.jpg`, `photo-mediumd.jpg`, `photo-large.jpg`, then the script looks for "small" and replaces with "medium" or "large" where appropriate.

NOTE: once the image loads, that's it - it does not dynamically change image out as you change the screensize. There is surely a solution that does that, but overkill if not needed.

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap 5.XX version have the new approach.
please try the code bellow if you are using bootstrap version greater than 5.

```html
<!--Visible only on mobile -->
<div class="d-block d-sm-none d-lg-none"> 
    <img src="small-image.jpg" />
</div>

<!-- Hidden only on mobile-->
<div class="d-none d-sm-block"> 
    <img src="large-image.jpg" />
</div>
```

**Refrence https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/display/**

Comment: There is already an answer to this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/25483170/2206209. But the fact that it will load or download all images whether it is being showed or not in all devices. The accepted answer is good enough so far https://stackoverflow.com/a/38889308/2206209.

Comment: Yes ofcourse. i was looking for the bootstrap 5 solution for loading same image for diffrent screen sizes using bootstrap sytles,