# How to change "image" in OpenCart header depending on device resolution

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, opencart

I have a problem with changing "image" in OpenCart header depending on device resolution. For example, when I check this home page on desktop resolution I have the following link to my header image `image/catalog/header_v6.png`. Could you help me please to change image when I view this page below desktop resolution? I read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25482765/bootstrap-change-image-according-to-device) with similar issue, but it didn't work.

```css
body {
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 400;
 color: #666;
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 20px;
 width: 100%;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
 color: #444;
}
/* default font size */
.fa {
 font-size: 14px;
}
/* Override the bootstrap defaults */
h1 {
 font-size: 33px;
}
h2 {
 font-size: 27px;
}
h3 {
 font-size: 21px;
}
h4 {
 font-size: 15px;
}
h5 {
 font-size: 12px;
}
h6 {
 font-size: 10.2px;
}
a {
 color: #23a1d1;
}
a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
}
legend {
 font-size: 18px;
 padding: 7px 0px
}
label {
 font-size: 12px;
 font-weight: normal;
}
select.form-control, textarea.form-control, input[type="text"].form-control, input[type="password"].form-control, input[type="datetime"].form-control, input[type="datetime-local"].form-control, input[type="date"].form-control, input[type="month"].form-control, input[type="time"].form-control, input[type="week"].form-control, input[type="number"].form-control, input[type="email"].form-control, input[type="url"].form-control, input[type="search"].form-control, input[type="tel"].form-control, input[type="color"].form-control {
 font-size: 12px;
}
.input-group input, .input-group select, .input-group .dropdown-menu, .input-group .popover {
 font-size: 12px;
}
.input-group .input-group-addon {
 font-size: 12px;
 height: 30px;
}
/* Fix some bootstrap issues */
span.hidden-xs, span.hidden-sm, span.hidden-md, span.hidden-lg {
 display: inline;
}

.nav-tabs {
 margin-bottom: 15px;
}
div.required .control-label:before {
 content: '* ';
 color: #F00;
 font-weight: bold;
}
/* Gradent to all drop down menus */
.dropdown-menu li > a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #ffffff;
 background-color: #229ac8;
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #23a1d1, #1f90bb);
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
/* top */
#top {
 background-color: #EEEEEE;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
 padding: 4px 0px 3px 0;
 margin: 0 0 20px 0;
 min-height: 40px;
}
#top .container {
 padding: 0 20px;
}
#top #form-currency .currency-select,
#top #form-language .language-select {
 text-align: left;
}
#top #form-currency .currency-select:hover,
#top #form-language .language-select:hover {
 text-shadow: none;
 color: #ffffff;
 background-color: #229ac8;
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #23a1d1, #1f90bb);
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
#top .btn-link, #top-links li, #top-links a {
 color: #888;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFF;
 text-decoration: none;
}
#top .btn-link:hover, #top-links a:hover {
 color: #444;
}
#top-links .dropdown-menu a {
 text-shadow: none;
}
#top-links .dropdown-menu a:hover {
 color: #FFF;
}
#top .btn-link strong {
 font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 14px;
}
#top-links {
 padding-top: 6px;
}
#top-links a + a {
 margin-left: 15px;
}
/* logo */
#logo {
 margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

.img-responsive{
 
 margin: 0 auto;
 
 }


/* search */
#search {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#search .input-lg {
 height: 40px;
 line-height: 20px;
 padding: 0 10px;
}
#search .btn-lg {
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 18px;
 padding: 10px 35px;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFF;
}
/* cart */
#cart {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 margin-top: 15px;
}
#cart > .btn {
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 18px;
 color: #FFF;
}
#cart.open > .btn {
 background-image: none;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 border: 1px solid #E6E6E6;
 color: #666;
 box-shadow: none;
 text-shadow: none;
}
#cart.open > .btn:hover {
 color: #444;
}
#cart .dropdown-menu {
 background: #eee;
 z-index: 1001;
}
#cart .dropdown-menu {
 min-width: 100%;
}
@media (max-width: 478px) {
 #cart .dropdown-menu {
  width: 100%;
 }
}
#cart .dropdown-menu table {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#cart .dropdown-menu li > div {
 min-width: 427px;
 padding: 0 10px;
}
@media (max-width: 478px) {
 #cart .dropdown-menu li > div {
  min-width: 100%;
 }
}
#cart .dropdown-menu li p {
 margin: 20px 0;
}
/* menu */
#menu {
 background-color: #229ac8;
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #23a1d1, #1f90bb);
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 border-color: #1f90bb #1f90bb #145e7a;
 min-height: 40px;
}
#menu .nav > li > a {
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 font-weight:400;
 
 font-size:18px;
 color: #fff;
 text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
 padding: 10px 35px 10px 35px;
 min-height: 15px;
 background-color: transparent;
}
#menu .nav > li > a:hover, #menu .nav > li.open > a {
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
#menu .dropdown-menu {
 padding-bottom: 0;
}
#menu .dropdown-inner {
 display: table;
}
#menu .dropdown-inner ul {
 display: table-cell;
}
#menu .dropdown-inner a {
 min-width: 160px;
 display: block;
 padding: 3px 20px;
 clear: both;
 line-height: 20px;
 color: #333333;
 font-size: 12px;
}
#menu .dropdown-inner li a:hover {
 color: #FFFFFF;
}
#menu .see-all {
 display: block;
 margin-top: 0.5em;
 border-top: 1px solid #DDD;
 padding: 3px 20px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
 -moz-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
 border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
 font-size: 12px;
}
#menu .see-all:hover, #menu .see-all:focus {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #ffffff;
 background-color: #229ac8;
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #23a1d1, #1f90bb);
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
#menu #category {
 float: left;
 padding-left: 15px;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: 700;
 line-height: 40px;
 color: #fff;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
#menu .btn-navbar {
 font-size: 15px;
 font-stretch: expanded;
 color: #FFF;
 padding: 2px 18px;
 float: right;
 background-color: #229ac8;
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #23a1d1, #1f90bb);
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 border-color: #1f90bb #1f90bb #145e7a;
}
#menu .btn-navbar:hover, #menu .btn-navbar:focus, #menu .btn-navbar:active, #menu .btn-navbar.disabled, #menu .btn-navbar[disabled] {
 color: #ffffff;
 background-color: #229ac8;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
 #menu .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
 }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
 #menu {
  border-radius: 4px;
 }
 #menu div.dropdown-inner > ul.list-unstyled {
  display: block;
 }
 #menu div.dropdown-menu {
  margin-left: 0 !important;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
 }
 #menu .dropdown-inner {
  display: block;
 }
 #menu .dropdown-inner a {
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
 }
 #menu .dropdown-menu a:hover,
 #menu .dropdown-menu ul li a:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
 }
 #menu .see-all {
  margin-top: 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  color: #fff;
 }
}
/* content */
#content {
 min-height: 600px;
}
/* footer */
footer {
 margin-top: 30px;
 padding-top: 30px;
 background-color: #303030;
 border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
 color: #e2e2e2;
}
footer hr {
 border-top: none;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
}
footer a {
 color: #ccc;
}
footer a:hover {
 color: #fff;
}
footer h5 {
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 font-size: 13px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #fff;
}
/* alert */
.alert {
 padding: 8px 14px 8px 14px;
}
/* breadcrumb */
.breadcrumb {
 margin: 0 0 20px 0;
 padding: 8px 0;
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.breadcrumb i {
 font-size: 15px;
}
.breadcrumb > li {
 text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFF;
 padding: 0 20px;
 position: relative;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
.breadcrumb > li + li:before {
 content: '';
 padding: 0;
}
.breadcrumb > li:after {
 content: '';
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 top: -3px;
 right: -5px;
 width: 26px;
 height: 26px;
 border-right: 1px solid #DDD;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
 transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.pagination {
 margin: 0;
}
/* buttons */
.buttons {
 margin: 1em 0;
}
.btn {
 padding: 7.5px 12px;
 font-size: 12px;
 border: 1px solid #cccccc;
 border-radius: 4px;
 box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
}
.btn-xs {
 font-size: 9px;
}
.btn-sm {
 font-size: 10.2px;
}
.btn-lg {
 padding: 10px 16px;
 font-size: 15px;
}
.btn-group > .btn, .btn-group > .dropdown-menu, .btn-group > .popover {
 font-size: 12px;
}
.btn-group > .btn-xs {
 font-size: 9px;
}
.btn-group > .btn-sm {
 font-size: 10.2px;
}
.btn-group > .btn-lg {
 font-size: 15px;
}
.btn-default {
 color: #777;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
 background-color: #e7e7e7;
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee, #dddddd);
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 border-color: #dddddd #dddddd #b3b3b3 #b7b7b7;
}
.btn-primary {
 color: #ffffff;
 text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
 background-color: #229ac8;
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #23a1d1, #1f90bb);
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 border-color: #1f90bb #1f90bb #145e7a;
}
.btn-primary:hover, .btn-primary:active, .btn-primary.active, .btn-primary.disabled, .btn-primary[disabled] {
 background-color: #1f90bb;
 background-position: 0 -15px;
}
.btn-warning {
 color: #ffffff;
 text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
 background-color: #faa732;
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fbb450, #f89406);
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 border-color: #f89406 #f89406 #ad6704;
}
.btn-warning:hover, .btn-warning:active, .btn-warning.active, .btn-warning.disabled, .btn-warning[disabled] {
 box-shadow: inset 0 1000px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.btn-danger {
 color: #ffffff;
 text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
 background-color: #da4f49;
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ee5f5b, #bd362f);
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 border-color: #bd362f #bd362f #802420;
}
.btn-danger:hover, .btn-danger:active, .btn-danger.active, .btn-danger.disabled, .btn-danger[disabled] {
 box-shadow: inset 0 1000px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.btn-success {
 color: #ffffff;
 text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
 background-color: #5bb75b;
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #62c462, #51a351);
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 border-color: #51a351 #51a351 #387038;
}
.btn-success:hover, .btn-success:active, .btn-success.active, .btn-success.disabled, .btn-success[disabled] {
 box-shadow: inset 0 1000px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.btn-info {
 color: #ffffff;
 text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
 background-color: #df5c39;
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #e06342, #dc512c);
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 border-color: #dc512c #dc512c #a2371a;
}
.btn-info:hover, .btn-info:active, .btn-info.active, .btn-info.disabled, .btn-info[disabled] {
 background-image: none;
 background-color: #df5c39;
}
.btn-link {
 border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
 cursor: pointer;
 color: #23A1D1;
 border-radius: 0;
}
.btn-link, .btn-link:active, .btn-link[disabled] {
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
 background-image: none;
 box-shadow: none;
}
.btn-inverse {
 color: #ffffff;
 text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
 background-color: #363636;
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #444444, #222222);
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 border-color: #222222 #222222 #000000;
}
.btn-inverse:hover, .btn-inverse:active, .btn-inverse.active, .btn-inverse.disabled, .btn-inverse[disabled] {
 background-color: #222222;
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #333333, #111111);
}
/* list group */
.list-group a {
 border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
 color: #888888;
 padding: 8px 12px;
}
.list-group a.active, .list-group a.active:hover, .list-group a:hover {
 color: #444444;
 background: #eeeeee;
 border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFF;
}
/* carousel */
.carousel-caption {
 color: #FFFFFF;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000000;
}
.carousel-control .icon-prev:before {
 content: '\f053';
 font-family: FontAwesome;
}
.carousel-control .icon-next:before {
 content: '\f054';
 font-family: FontAwesome;
}
/* product list */
.product-thumb {
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 overflow: auto;
}
.product-thumb .image {
 text-align: center;
}
.product-thumb .image a {
 display: block;
}
.product-thumb .image a:hover {
 opacity: 0.8;
}
.product-thumb .image img {
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}
.product-grid .product-thumb .image {

 float: none;
}
@media (min-width: 767px) {
.product-list .product-thumb .image {
 float: left;
 padding: 0 15px;
}
}
.product-thumb h4 {
 font-weight: bold;
}
.product-thumb .caption {
 padding: 0 20px;
 min-height: 180px;
}
.product-list .product-thumb .caption {
 margin-left: 230px;
}
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
.product-grid .product-thumb .caption {
 min-height: 210px;
 padding: 0 10px;
}
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
.product-list .product-thumb .caption {
 min-height: 0;
 margin-left: 0;
 padding: 0 10px;
}
.product-grid .product-thumb .caption {
 min-height: 0;
}
}
.product-thumb .rating {
 padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.rating .fa-stack {
 font-size: 8px;
}
.rating .fa-star-o {
 color: #999;
 font-size: 15px;
}
.rating .fa-star {
 color: #FC0;
 font-size: 15px;
}
.rating .fa-star + .fa-star-o {
 color: #E69500;
}
h2.price {
 margin: 0;
}
.product-thumb .price {
 color: #444;
}
.product-thumb .price-new {
 font-weight: 600;
}
.product-thumb .price-old {
 color: #999;
 text-decoration: line-through;
 margin-left: 10px;
}
.product-thumb .price-tax {
 color: #999;
 font-size: 12px;
 display: block;
}
.product-thumb .button-group {
 border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
 background-color: #eee;
 overflow: auto;
}
.product-list .product-thumb .button-group {
 border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
 .product-list .product-thumb .button-group {
  border-left: none;
 }
}
.product-thumb .button-group button {
 width: 60%;
 border: none;
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
 background-color: #eee;
 color: #888;
 line-height: 38px;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
.product-thumb .button-group button + button {
 width: 20%;
 border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.product-thumb .button-group button:hover {
 color: #444;
 background-color: #ddd;
 text-decoration: none;
 cursor: pointer;
}
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
 .product-thumb .button-group button, .product-thumb .button-group button + button {
  width: 33.33%;
 }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
 .product-thumb .button-group button, .product-thumb .button-group button + button {
  width: 33.33%;
 }
}
.thumbnails {
 overflow: auto;
 clear: both;
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
.thumbnails > li {
 margin-left: 20px;
}
.thumbnails {
 margin-left: -20px;
}
.thumbnails > img {
 width: 100%;
}
.image-additional a {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 padding: 5px;
 display: block;
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.image-additional {
 max-width: 78px;
}
.thumbnails .image-additional {
 float: left;
 margin-left: 20px;
}









@media (min-width: 1200px) {
 #content .col-lg-2:nth-child(6n+1),
 #content .col-lg-2:nth-child(6n+1),
 #content .col-lg-3:nth-child(4n+1),
 #content .col-lg-4:nth-child(3n+1),
 #content .col-lg-6:nth-child(2n+1) {
  clear:left;
 }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
 #content .col-md-2:nth-child(6n+1),
 #content .col-md-2:nth-child(6n+1),
 #content .col-md-3:nth-child(4n+1),
 #content .col-md-4:nth-child(3n+1),
 #content .col-md-6:nth-child(2n+1) {
  clear:left;
 }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
 #content .col-sm-2:nth-child(6n+1),
 #content .col-sm-2:nth-child(6n+1),
 #content .col-sm-3:nth-child(4n+1),
 #content .col-sm-4:nth-child(3n+1),
 #content .col-sm-6:nth-child(2n+1) {
  clear:left;
 }
}

/* fixed colum left + content + right*/
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    #column-left  .product-layout .col-md-3 {
       width: 100%;
    }

 #column-left + #content .product-layout .col-md-3 {
       width: 50%;
    }

 #column-left + #content + #column-right .product-layout .col-md-3 {
       width: 100%;
    }

    #content + #column-right .product-layout .col-md-3 {
       width: 100%;
    }
}

/* fixed product layouts used in left and right columns */
#column-left .product-layout, #column-right .product-layout {
 width: 100%;
}

/* fixed mobile cart quantity input */
.input-group .form-control[name^=quantity] {
 min-width: 50px;
}

/* Missing focus and border color to overwrite bootstrap */
.btn-info:hover, .btn-info:active, .btn-info.active, .btn-info.disabled, .btn-info[disabled] {
    background-image: none;
    background-color: #df5c39;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div id="logo">
          <?php if ($logo) { ?>
          <a href="<?php echo $home; ?>"><img src="image/catalog/header_v6.png" title="<?php echo $name; ?>" alt="<?php echo $name; ?>" class="img-responsive" /></a>
          <?php } else { ?>
          <h1><a href="<?php echo $home; ?>"><?php echo $name; ?></a></h1>
          <?php } ?>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-sm-2" >
      
      <div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12 pull-right"><?php echo $cart; ?></div></div>

      <div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12 pull-right"><?php echo $search; ?></div></div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Why do you prefer change the image rather than resize the image?
If your theme is using Bootstrap (as the default theme), [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25483170/4094098) seems appropriate.

Comment: I wanted to change the image of large header which is make like a banner. I checked my page on a small device (iPhone 4), and the image becomes too small. I just wanted to show the the small part of the header's title on small devices. Thank you for your comment!