# How to image swap based on screen size?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, screen-size

I recently started experimenting with bootstrap and scaling things to size when the screen is shrunk. If I have an image that needs to be at least 300px to be readable but the screen is only 250px wide (just for example) they would have to scroll left and right to see the whole image. On ford.com they actually swap the larger image out for a similar image that is smaller, more fit for the screen. Then as you drag the screen larger, it switches back to the larger image. Im assuming this has to do with some form of JS and screen size dimensions. Any thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap change image according to device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25482765/bootstrap-change-image-according-to-device)

Comment: Post the code you've tried so far.

Answer (score 4):

Technically the feature you're describing could be achieved through either **css**, **html** or **javascript**.

In **CSS** you can use **media queries** to load your images through the **background** property,

```
.image {
    background: url("image.jpg");
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 250px) {
    .image {
        background: url("alternative-image.jpg");
    }
}
```

or, in case you had both **images loaded in the html document**, through the **display** property.

```
.image {
    display: initial;
}
.alternative-image {
    display: none;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 250px) {
    .image {
        display: none;
    }
    .alternative-image {
        display: initial;
    }
}
```

Read more about media queries [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp).

In **HTML** you can use the **picture** and **source elements**,

```
<picture>
    <source media="(min-width: 250px)" srcset="image.jpg" />
    <img src="alternative-image.jpg" />
</picture>
```

or the simpler alternative, the **srcset attribute**.

```
<img src="alternative-image.jpg" srcset="image.jpg 250px" />
```

Read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_source_srcset.asp).

Finally, in **JavaScript** you can use the **window size properties** to build a function that loads the right image for each size **every time the window is resized**.

```
window.onresize = function () {
    if (window.innerWidth < 250) {
        image.setAttribute("src", "alternative-image.jpg");
    } else {
        image.setAttribute("src", "image.jpg");
    }
}
```

Read a bit about the window size properties [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_innerheight.asp).

PS. Do **NOT** directly use these examples, as they are **incomplete** and **unoptimized**. Their only purpose is to **mock** the use of the resources they reference.

Comment: I really like your examples. Thank you! One question however: In your javascript example, won't all of the images still be downloaded to the client? (I'm trying to build something to prevent unnecessarily large images from being downloaded to the client)

Answer (score 1):

this can be archive in 2 ways.

1. there is a class in bootstrap V3 `img-responsive` if you add this class in image tag then it will auto resize when viewport is smaller then image size. Reference : http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images-responsive
2. OR you can use `srcset` attribute of image tag

example:
`<img src="small.jpg" srcset="medium.jpg 1000w, large.jpg 2000w" alt="yah">`
in above example you can set image path in `srcset` in first parameter and on second is image width. in this Browser auto detect viewport width and based on that it will load image.